# How to make REST API call in smartstore in React Native

Tags: community, react-native, smartstore

I am working on integrating salesforce with react native for the first time. I have an offline feature for that I am using smartStore. Now I want make REST API calls in smartStore. After checking documentation I found a link but it has code only for native and hybrid apps. Can anyone please guide me what should I do?

I am referring following link
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/offline_populate_soup.htm

Comment: Check https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Templates/tree/dev/MobileSyncExplorerReactNative , it has what you're looking for

Comment: @identigral, I am already referring to that template I haven't found any REST API